# How to block screenshots in flutter on only one page?

Tags: flutter, dart

I was wondering how to block screenshots in flutter on only one page. I read there is a way by blocking screenshots in a flutter app, with: `getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);` but the way I understood it was, that when I do this, screenshots are blocked in the entire app.

So my question is, is there a way to block screenshots on only one page in the flutter app in **android** and **IOS**. On every other page screenshots should still be possible. If someone knows a solution, please share it with me, because I couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, I have found a way to achieve what I have desired. With the package: `flutter_windowmanager` you can add flags and also remove flags.
So it was pretty simple all I had to do, was add this:

```
Future<void> secureScreen() async {
        await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
        }
```

to the `initState` of the page I wanted to protect against screenshots. And then add this to the dispose method of the page:

```
Future<void> clearSecureScreen() async {
        await FlutterWindowManager.clearFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
      }
```

It is important that the page is removed from the stack otherwise dispose isn't called, but i think most people already know that.

Now we achieved the desired behavior it is now impossible to take screenshots, screen recordings in any way, as far as i know.

I hope I could help someone with my post !

Answer (score 0):

You could use some sort of conditioning where you can check a boolean. If that boolean is true then screenshots are blocked otherwise they are not. You can change it to true in initState when you move to the specific screen otherwise false.

Comment: Sounds good but, I need to write the line in the MainActivity class, far as I know. How can I create a boolean in my dart code that affects code in the MainActivity class ?