# How i can Block screenshoot in flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to block screenshoot in flutter app, and block any app to take screen in my app help me

I use the native code but there are user can take screen in my app.
I want prevent any user to take the screenshoot in my app,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to block screenshots in flutter on only one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65389302/how-to-block-screenshots-in-flutter-on-only-one-page)

Comment: How are you going to prevent people from just shooting it with a second phone?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [flutter_windowmanager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager) package in my Fintech flutter application to block ScreenShoots

setup flutter_windowmanager in your main() method like this

```
await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
```

P.S. I have tested it only on Android